# Writing a transformer (from one object schema to another) in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a nosql database where I know the schema of my documents. In my react app I have a slightly different schema. I want to define both interfaces in typescript as well as transforming from one interface to another.

The following code works just fine

```js
interface backendPersons {
    [id: string]: {
        name: string;
        hairColor: string;
    };
}

interface appPersons {
    [id: string]: {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        hairColor: string;
    };
}

type Transformer<fromType, toType> = (data: fromType) => toType;

const personsTransformer: Transformer<backendPersons, appPersons> = data => {
    let res: appPersons = {};
    for (let k of Object.keys(data)) {
        res[k] = {...data[k], id: k}
    }
    return res
};

const backendPerson = {
    'john': {
        name: 'John Doe',
        hairColor: 'black'
    }
}
const appPerson = personsTransformer(backendPerson);
```

but lets say I want to have a more generic transformer function since I'd have to do the same transformation for a bunch of interfaces. I have the following but it doesn't work (*TS2322* and *TS7053*)

```js
const transformer = <fromType, toType>(data: fromType): Transformer<fromType, toType> => {
    let res: toType = {};
    for (let k of Object.keys(data)) {
        res[k] = {...data[k], id: k}
    }
    return res
}
const appPersons = transformer<backendPersons, appPersons>(backendPerson);
```

Actually I'd like to extend the functionality so the inner transformation wouldn't just be `{...data[k], id: k}` but it could be any transformation given `data` and `k` given as an optional argument in the `transformer` call.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is..

Comment: I’d like to define something like in the second codeblock. But that doesn’t work. Create a generic transformer to transform a object defined as interface A to a object defined as interface B.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If not, what  about this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/svfbtw?file=index.ts